# Calculated field based upon Date and Time field serves up a weird number

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I have a list of learning courses. One column is a Date and Time column showing when a learning course will run.

I wanted to use this column to build a unique course ID. However when I set up another column and used the formula [Date] it served up 45,487 for the date 14/07/2024.

Can anyone let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Can you add the formula you are using to your question? Also, it depends on the return type you are using for your calculated column. Are you using "Number" return type?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the `TEXT()` function to convert the date time column in specific format.

**Example 1**:

Formula:

```
=TEXT([Date],"mmddyyyy")
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Example 2**:

Formula:

```
=TEXT([Date],"mm-dd-yyyy")
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[Choice Column 5]`

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))